# Do multiple (query) check (optimze) in PHP

Tags: php, mysqli, mysqli-multi-query

i want ask, is there any How to short my script

First Check, if get `uid`, do Second and Third check

```
$result = mysqli_fetch_row(mysqli_query($con, "SELECT MAX(`uid`) FROM `pvpgn_bnet`"));
if($result) {
    Do Second and First Check();
}
```

Second Check

```
$result = mysqli_fetch_row(mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `pvpgn_bnet` WHERE acct_email = '" . $email . "'"));
    if($result) {
        errorMsg();
    }
```

Third Check

```
$result = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con, "SELECT `uid` FROM `pvpgn_bnet` WHERE acct_username = '" . $username . "'"), MYSQLI_BOTH);
if($result) {
    errorMsg();
}
```

Comment: Is this some sort of user authentication check? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: the second and third can be done in one trip, just add `OR` , and please, you're using mysqli, just use binding

Comment: first check, only for get `uid` (coz database not AI), second for check email if exist, and third for check if username is exist, if nothing error do insert script

Comment: @kevinabelita im newbie in PHP, can u give example how to do that?

Comment: First, make it AI. Second, get rid of the first query, as it makes no sense. Then learn to use prepared statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know what the first filter is for (it doesnt make sense), but the second and third can be combined. Consider this example:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM pvpgn_bnet WHERE acct_email=? OR acct_username=?")
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $email, $username);
$stmt->execute();
// other processes

$res = $stmt->get_result();
while($row = $res->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    // what ever you want to do here
}
```